# Android accelerometer, make sound when device is flat

Tags: android, audio, accelerometer

I am trying to build a simple level app. What I want is when the device is totally flat (x,y values of accelerometer almost 0) for the device to produce a beep sound after 5 seconds, not immediately.

I am using the following code, and I do not know what I must changed in order for the sound to always works after 5 seconds and not randomly or immediately. Can somebody help me?

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
  x = event.values[0];
  y = event.values[1];
  long actualTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
  if(x > -0.1 && x < 0.1 && y > -0.1 && y < 0.1) {
    if(actualTime - lastUpdate >= 5000) {
      return;
    }
    lastUpdate = actualTime;
    try {
      AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("beep.wav");
      mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
      mMediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
      afd.close();
      mMediaplayer.prepare();
      mMediaplayer.start();
      mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
          //mp.setLooping(false);
          mp.stop();
          mp.release();
        }
      });
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a handler.  When the device goes flat (where that code plays a sound) post a delayed message to the handler for 5 seconds from now.  Have the handler play the sound when it receives a message.

That's the standard way for "do X in Y seconds".

Answer (score 0):

I think that a Timer would work nicely for you.  Perhaps something like this, where you cancel the timer and start a new timer every time you detect motion:

define your timer in your activity (and make sure you cancel it when you leave the activity)

```
Timer lastTouchedTimer = null;
```

Then change your onSensorChanged like this:

```
  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];

        if(x > -0.1 && x < 0.1 && y > -0.1 && y < 0.1) {
            if (lastTouchedTimer == null) {
                lastTouchedTimer = new Timer();
            } else
                lastTouchedTimer.cancel();
            }
            lastTouchedTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("beep.wav");
                        mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
                        mMediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                        afd.close();
                        mMediaplayer.prepare();
                        mMediaplayer.start();
                        mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                //mp.setLooping(false);
                                mp.stop();
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, 5000);
        }
    }
```

Here is an activity, which I use in a sample activity.

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    Timer lastTouchedTimer;
    MediaPlayer mMediaplayer;
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        SensorEventListener newListener = new SensorEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
                float x = sensorEvent.values[0];
                float y = sensorEvent.values[1];

                if(x > -0.1 && x < 0.1 && y > -0.1 && y < 0.1) {
                    if (lastTouchedTimer == null) {
                        lastTouchedTimer = new Timer();
                    } else
                        lastTouchedTimer.cancel();
                }
                lastTouchedTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd("beep.wav");
                            mMediaplayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            mMediaplayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                            afd.close();
                            mMediaplayer.prepare();
                            mMediaplayer.start();
                            mMediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                    //mp.setLooping(false);
                                    mp.stop();
                                    mp.release();
                                }
                            });
                        } catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, 5000);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int i) {
                //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
        };
    }
}
```

It uses a very simple xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Heallo World, MyActivity"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your method but then my app can not even open..Do you know why?

Comment: There was at least one small typo.  I've edited my response and included my activity from my little sample I wrote.  I'm not sure why your app is not loading, but I do know that this one does.